# limits function

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{x+3}{x^2-8}=-5/4$$  I need to prove the above by definition of limit.

I tried by definition $|\frac{x+3}{x^2-8}+5/4|=|\frac{5x^2+4x-28}{4x^2-32}|                $
and I need to prove this is $<\epsilon$
I need to use only definition of limit of function, which mean I have $\delta>|x-2|$ and I have to make this expression somehow be $|x-2|$ so I can use the $\delta$.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried editing your question to make it more readable but I still think it needs to improve.

Comment: Thank you,im not native speaker, and its more hard to write in "math" im trying my best

Comment: What does, ‘limit as $x$ does *not*  tend to $2$’ mean?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$5x^2+4x-28=(x-2)(5x+14) $$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to help. And Happy New Year!  -Mark